# Nginx - Conditionally serve WebP via Nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, proxy

Trying to conditionally serve WebP images in browsers that accept that mime type. I'm having issues implementing a known solution into my existing Nginx setup.

I'm attempting to use the below method of implementing WebP:

```
  map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
    "~*webp"  ".webp";
  }

  server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
      try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
    }
  }
```

[from here](https://github.com/igrigorik/webp-detect/blob/master/nginx.conf)

But trying to find a way to use it with my existing nginx config has been getting me nothing but errors. My existing config (Nginx proxy on AWS Elastic BeanStalk with Node.js) appears to be reverse proxied to the node.js process.

Where I need to put this in my existing Nginx configuration is below:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

How do I impliment the try_files directive in the above Nginx config, in order to conditionally serve WebP images?

Comment: The `try_files` directive is only useful for serving static files. Your question implies that the Node.js app is serving the images.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've adjusted the question. Please let me know if its still not clear.

Comment: Are you saying that you **do** want `nginx` to serve these files statically (if they exist within the document root), otherwise pass the request to node.js (only if the static file does not exist)?

Comment: In either instance I want `nginx` to handle the serving of static assets. When encountering any request for png or jpeg located in the public /images directory, `nginx` should look for the same uri but with the webp suffix. If the file isn't 404 then serve the file with the webp suffix.

For instance, when images/someimg.jpg try images/someimg.webp

Answer (score 0):

Use a named location as the default action of the `try_files` directive (rather than the `=404` response). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details. For example:

```
map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
    "~*webp"  ".webp";
}

upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    root /path/to/document/root;

    location / {
        try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri @nodejs;
    }

    location @nodejs {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

If the static file is found in the directory structure below `/path/to/document/root`, conditionally with `.webp` appended, then `nginx` will serve up the file. Otherwise control will be passed to the named location and the URI will be sent to the node.js process.

Comment: For some reason this always returns with the original content type and never with webp. I'll investigate further. In the mean time I've decided to implement with extra markup via `<picture>` element.